# how to change the row property value of textarea dynamically according to text input? [In ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So far I have done this:

```
<textarea rows='2' onChange={e => setSomething(e.target.value)}
    className='form-control text-area ' value={something} placeholder='write something'>
</textarea>
```

output:

[image]

**Expected Requirement:**

I need to change the value of row property dynamically according to the text line.
If the number of text line increases, then row property value will also increase.
But if it is more than 8, then we have to use scroll-bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you actually want is to dynamically resize the textarea to match the content:

- You can do that by setting the `height` of the textarea to `auto` and then to the value of `textarea.scrollHeight`.
- If you don't want the user to be able to make the textarea smaller than that, also set `minHeight` to that value:
- You can limit the maximum height with `maxHeight`, and making sure `minHeight` is not set to a value greater than that. Beyond that, scrollbars will appear:

```js
function resizeTextArea(textarea) {
  const { style, value } = textarea;

  // The 4 corresponds to the 2 2px borders (top and bottom):
  style.height = style.minHeight = 'auto';
  style.minHeight = `${ Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight + 4, parseInt(textarea.style.maxHeight)) }px`;
  style.height = `${ textarea.scrollHeight + 4 }px`;
}

const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
  resizeTextArea(textarea);
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="max-height: 140px; "></textarea>
```

An improved version of would not shrink down the textarea if the user has manually expanded it, unless they shrink it back to fit the content. It would, however, still expand automatically if the content becomes larger than the user-defined height:

```js
function resizeTextArea(textarea, userDefinedHeight = 0) {
  const { style, value } = textarea;

  // The 4 corresponds to the 2 2px borders (top and bottom):
  style.height = style.minHeight = 'auto';
  style.minHeight = `${ Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight + 4, parseInt(textarea.style.maxHeight)) }px`;
  style.height = `${ Math.max(textarea.scrollHeight + 4, userDefinedHeight) }px`;
}

const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

let userDefinedHeight = 0;

textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
  resizeTextArea(textarea, userDefinedHeight);
});

textarea.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    const { height, minHeight } = textarea.style;

    // Do not shrink beyond user-defined values (if they expand it manually),
    // but go back to auto-resizing if they shrink it back to the content size:
    userDefinedHeight = height === minHeight ? 0 : parseInt(height, 10);
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="max-height: 140px; "></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you set row property dynamically according to the number of newlines are there as:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(2);
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    function setTextAreaInput(e) {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setValue(val);

        const newLines = val.match(/\n/g)?.length;
        if (!newLines) setRows(2);
        else if (newLines < 8) setRows(newLines + 1);
        else setRows(8);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <textarea
                rows={rows}
                onChange={(e) => setTextAreaInput(e)}
                className="form-control text-area "
                value={value}
                placeholder="write something"></textarea>
        </div>
    );
}
```